# Javascript: How can I use a variable name when updating a form value?

Tags: javascript

Here is part of the function:

```
function updateResponse(question, answer) {
    questionId = 'q'+question;
    document.forms[0].questionId.value = answer;
```

Calling the function with something like:

```
<td onClick='javascript:updateResponse(1, 1);'>
```

The form element I want it to update looks something like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='q1' value='' />
```

Using Firefox web console I get:

```
TypeError: document.forms[0].questionId is undefined
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Found this after much googling and it works. Still seems like there may be a more graceful way to achieve this though?

```
eval(\"document.forms[0].\"+questionId+\".value = answer;\");
```

Comment: You do not need the `javascript:` prefix there..

Comment: removed that, thanks. still the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure there's an input in the form that has the name questionId:

`document.forms[0][questionId].value`

And you should use var to avoid global variable:

`var questionId = 'q' + question;`

Comment: questionId is the name of the variable. It's value should be q1 or similar.

Comment: Thanks. Added var but still getting the same error. To be clear, I want javascript to substitute the word questionId with it's value 'q1'. It looks to me like it is trying to find a form element called 'questionId'. It needs to find 'q1', 'q2', 'q3' etc depending on the *value* of variable 'questionId'.

Comment: Have you even tried the first JavaScript line I answered, e.g.: `document.forms[0][questionId].value = answer;`? That would satisfy your need whatever value the questionId holds.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have posted the result. When using

    `document.forms[0].[questionId].value = answer;`

I get: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Comment: You've added an extra '.'.

Comment: Ok I took away the extra '.' so it read `document.forms[0]questionId.value = answer;` however this gives:

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement